# Persisting JPA entities with entity fields possible?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, entity

If I have an entity such as the following:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    private Address address;
}
```

And the Address is also an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {...}
```

Does persisting the Customer in turn persist its contained Address? Or is this not possible at all? The idea was basically to have a main entity that consists of its fields, some of which are entities themselves that will be stored in individual tables. Some of the fields of Customer are unique in that I also would like a Customer table for that data. Unless I'm just missing it, I haven't been able to find this answer. This was something I was just curious about and I'm not currently on a machine where I can try it, so I wanted to ask first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just reinvented the OneToOne (or ManyToOne) association. This is of course covered by any tutorial/book about JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible and JPA basics. But you have to define the associations between entities in your entity classes.

I recommend reading a good tutorial on this topic, e.g. the [Java EE6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options depending on your domain model:

- removing the @Entity from address and annotate it with @Embeddable
- mapping the Address in the Person with: @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})